# Delete the last two rows of a worksheet in Excel that is dynamic using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I had found a solution that looks at a table, but I am trying to delete the last two rows of a worksheet.

The code I am referring to is,

```vb
Dim wsR2 As Worksheet
Set wsR2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Journal")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = wsR2.ListObjects("xJrnl").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

wsR2.ListObjects("xJrnl").ListRows(LastRow).Delete
```

How do I edit the code to be used for a worksheet rather than a table. My sheet name is "Sheet1".

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part of your task is to reliably find the last row on the sheet. There are several ways, each with its own advantages and disadvantages. One of the solutions is below (a fragment of the solution from [Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) is used - I recommend reading it).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Del2lastRows()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, LastCell As Range
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set LastCell = sh.Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                    After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    
    If LastCell.Row > 1 Then
        LastCell.Offset(-1).Resize(2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    ' reset find dialog after using LastRow()
    sh.Cells.Find what:="", _
               After:=ActiveCell, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               LookAt:=xlPart, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, _
               SearchFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked great and I did read the article you suggested. Very informative thank you.